# Ubuntu replaced my /home directory after install

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, debian, ubiquity

I switched from Debian 9 to Ubuntu 16.04. When installing, I used the option 'manual' in the partitioner in the installer. There, I only formatted the '/' partition and left the rest as is, in order to retain info on that disk. Now it shows that my former 450 GB former /home partition is now a separate disk, and /home on Ubuntu is only 35 gigs and empty. Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks

Here's the lsblk output:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop1    7:1    0   115M  1 loop /snap/vlc/4
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
loop0    7:0    0  80,5M  1 loop /snap/core/2462
sda      8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk 
├─sda4   8:4    0   3,7G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda2   8:2    0  37,6G  0 part / 
├─sda3   8:3    0   424G  0 part /media/nenad/f65fe2e0-5d9d-4228-943f-    0db3a23f
└─sda1   8:1    0   476M  0 part /boot/efi
```

Comment: Add the output of `lsblk` to you question please.

Comment: do you mean seperate partition??

Comment: if your old /home was in a different partition; it's probably just not mounted.  the setup requires a /home mounted in order to create user id, so it'll create one being a directory.  when you mount your old (deb 9) /home partition it'll 'hide' the directory ubuntu created on install most likely.  this is supposition, as I don't have details of your partitions or install (your initial post is vague as other noted)

Comment: Assuming your old home partition is `sda3`, all you need is to mount it in `/home/$USER`. You could have done this in the installation menu already, but afterwards is also fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the UUID of the partition with `blkid` and add it to your `/etc/fstab` as follows (assuming it has an `ext4` file system):

```
UUID=paste_your_UUID_here /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
```

Then a simple `sudo mount -a` (or a reboot) suffices to mount it and it is mounted automatically from now on.

---

An example how you can set a partition's mountpoint in the installation gives this screenshot:
[image]
Of course this is different from your case – here the home partition `/dev/sda6` is set to be formatted with `reiserfs`.

Comment: Thank you, this works!

Any idea where to mark it in the installer next time? I thought not formatting it and leaving it marked as /home will do the trick.

Comment: @uxbal In the manual(!) installer you choose the partitions's mountpoints, e. g. you chose `/dev/sda2` for `/`, setting the mointpoint for other partitions works the same and is *not bound to format* the partition.

Comment: @uxbal I added a screenshot that gives an idea.

Comment: Oh, than i managed to miss the mount point part it seems. I was just focused on not formatting. Thanks again!